# Selenium - How to get info from elements that have the same class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, video, youtube

I'm trying to make a python app that extracts all of the youtube titles of a youtube channel's videos.

I'm currently attempting to do it using selenium.

```
def getVideoTitles():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/{username}/PycharmProjects/YoutubeChannelVideos/chromedriver")
    driver.get(googleYoutubePage())

    titleElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-lockup-content")
    print(titleElement.text) #it prints out title, + views, hours ago, and "CC"
     #I suck at selenium so lets just store the title and cut everything after it
```

The class_name yt-lockup-content is the class name for each video on a youtube channel's /videos page.
In the code above I am able to get the title for the first youtube video on that page. But I want to iterate through all of the youtube titles (in other words, I want to iterate through every single yt-lockup-content element) in order to store the .text.

But I was wondering how do I access the yt-lockup-content[2] persay. Which in other words would be the second video on that page, that has the same class name

Here is my full code.
Feel free to play

```
'''

'''
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

def getChannelName():
    print("Please enter the channel that you would like to scrape video titles...")
    channelName = input()
    googleSearch = "https://www.google.ca/search?q=%s+youtube&oq=%s+youtube&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2898j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%s+youtube&*" %(channelName, channelName, channelName)
    print(googleSearch)
    return googleSearch

def googleYoutubePage():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/{username}/PycharmProjects/YoutubeChannelVideos/chromedriver")
    driver.get(getChannelName())
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("s") #this is where the link to the proper youtube page lives
    keys = element.text #this grabs the link to the youtube page + other crap that will be cut

    splitKeys = keys.split(" ") #this needs to be split, because aside from the link it grabs the page description, which we need to truncate
    linkToPage = splitKeys[0] #this is where the link lives

    for index, char in enumerate(linkToPage): #this loops over the link to find where the stuff beside the link begins (which is unecessary)
        if char == "\n":
            extraCrapStartsHere = index #it starts here, we know everything beyond here can be cut


    link = ""
    for i in range(extraCrapStartsHere): #the offical link will be everything in the linkToPage up to where we found suitable to cut
        link = link + linkToPage[i]

    videosPage = link + "/videos"
    print(videosPage)
    return videosPage

def getVideoTitles():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/{username}/PycharmProjects/YoutubeChannelVideos/chromedriver")
    driver.get(googleYoutubePage())

    titleElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-lockup-content")
    print(titleElement.text) #it prints out title, + views, hours ago, and "CC"
                            #I suck at selenium so lets just store the title and cut everything after it


def main():
    getVideoTitles()

main()
```

Comment: i can't figure it out. I've done this... textelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = yt-lockup-content")[1] but when i run  print(textelement.text) i get an error

Comment: No, doesn't work, thanks for the suggestion tho. I'll keep trying other things

Comment: nope tried that as well as fixing the spelling of yt-uix-TITLE-link. Thanks anyways again tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an overly complicated way to do this. You can just navigate directly to the videos page using the URL, https://www.youtube.com/user/{ChannelName}/videos, loop through the titles, and print them.

```
print("Please enter the channel that you would like to scrape video titles...")
channelName = input()
videosUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/user/%s/videos" % channelName
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/{username}/PycharmProjects/YoutubeChannelVideos/chromedriver")
driver.get(videosUrl)
for title in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yt-uix-tile-link")
    print(title.text)
```

Comment: holy crap your for title in driver loop worked! Except, I'm not gonna do 
videosUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/user/%s/videos" % channelName because each youtube channel doesnt have a url corresponding to their channel name. Some have unique codes. like this page https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCboMX_UNgaPBsUOIgasn3-Q/videos

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `driver.find_element_by_class_name` you can use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` which will return a list of all the elements with the specified class name.

From there you can iterate through the list and get the titles of each youtube video.

Comment: Good idea but didn't work ;/ I got a traceback that said that it couldn't find that element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".yt-lockup-content")`?

Comment: @MichaelLions Is this scrolling issue?

Comment: no,it's not a scrolling issue. I want to print out all of the content for the element that holds youtube video titles. And there are multiple videos, that each have the same class name

Comment: @MichaelLions It might be possible the element you are looking for is not in view and is somewhere at down.